# Complete second-order model with 2 quantitative and 1 qualitative variables

Tags: self-study, multiple-regression

I want to check if what I have for the equation for the second-order model relating y to 2 quantitative and 1 qualitative variables (3 levels) is correct:

$\mathbb{E}(y)= \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \beta_3x_1x_2 + \beta_4x_1^2 + \beta_5x_2^2 + $

$\beta_6x_3 + \beta_7x_4 +$

$\beta_8x_1x_3 + \beta_9x_1x_4 + \beta_{10}x_2x_3 + \beta_{11}x_2x_4 + $

$\beta_{12}x_1x_2x_3 + \beta_{13}x_1x_2x_4 + $

$\beta_{14}x_1^2x_3 + \beta_{15}x_1^2x_4 +$

$\beta_{16}x_2^2x_3 + \beta_{17}x_2^2x_4$

Here, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the quantitative variables, $x_3$ and $x_4$ indicate the 2 levels of the qualitative variable. So basically,

1st line: complete second-order model with 2 quantitative variables

2nd line: 2 levels of the qualitative variable

3rd line: interaction between first-order term of quantitative variables and the levels

4th line: interaction between interaction of quantitative and the levels

5th line: interaction between second-order term of first quantitative variable and the levels

6th line: interaction between second-order term of second quantitative variable and the levels